# Java can't read an image with javax.imageio or Sanselan

Tags: java, image, image-processing, javax.imageio

I want to read an image to scale it using awt and Apache Commons Imaging, previously known as Apache Commons Sanselan
I can not scale the image but I can see it in the browser properly as **jpg** without any problem.
Getting the image info using

`Sanselan.getMetadata(fileData)`

I get this info:

```
No Exif metadata.
Photoshop (IPTC) metadata:
```

The code

```
public static byte[] scale(byte[] fileData, int width, int height) {

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);

        try {

            BufferedImage img = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(in);

            ....

            return buffer.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e1) {

            System.out.println  ("e1 -> " + e1.getMessage());

            try {

                BufferedImage img = Sanselan.getBufferedImage(in);

            } catch (ImageReadException | IOException e2) {

                System.out.println  ("e2 -> " + e2.getMessage());
            }

        }

        return fileData;
    }
```

but I got this exceptions:

```
e1 -> Unsupported Image Type
e2 -> Can't parse this format.
```

Comment: You are very much over-tagging. What has this todo with java-io or awt? Then: what kind of image file did you try to load? Did you try other formats? Are you sure the file is a valid image?

Comment: The problem seems to be a JPEG the internal `JPEGImageReader` can't read. Can you attach the problematic image? You could also try adding my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO JPEG plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg) which supports CMYK JPEGs and other formats the internal reader can't read.

Answer (score 1):

Image scaling can be done without external libraries.

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(URL);
Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) for further inspiration.

Comment: The OP's code throws an exception due to an unsupported image type, your code will have the exact same problem on line 1... Also, if `ImageIO.read()` succeeds, it returns a `BufferedImage` and you [should not use `getScaledInstance() on a `BufferedImage`](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611).